# change label text while Winform is open

Tags: c#, winforms, file-upload, progress-bar, label

I am trying to Change the text of a Label after it is shown in a Progressbar,
i want to Show the number of files that are being uploaded, and the number that has been so far.

i have created a ProgressBar winform, and my (beginner) plan was to do it like this:

```
public StatusUpload(String saved)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        AmountSaved.Text = saved;
    }
```

but when i try to Change it from another class,
i can only define it in the beginning

```
StatusUpload Progressbar = new StatusUpload("Total Saved: 0/" + selection.Count);
```

and can't Change it afterwards anymore, what should i do?
(i want to Change it later during the Loop so i can write 1/2, and then after the final Loop 2/2)

Comment: You'll need to make "Progressbar" a member of your class instead of a local variable.  So you can refer to it again later in another method.  This doesn't have anything to do with [winforms], you'll find help with learning objected oriented programming in lots of books and schools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing a big workload in the background. I would advise using a Background Worker :http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

You generate the Backgroundworker when you want to upload your data. Then you subscribe to the Events:

```
public event DoWorkEventHandler DoWork
```

Put your uploading code here. After i.e. you finished 1/2 files you call `ReportProgress(1);`

```
   public event ProgressChangedEventHandler ProgressChanged
```

This is thrown if you call `ReportProgress();` . Then you update your Progressbar with:

```
this.yourProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
```

}

```
public event RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler RunWorkerCompleted
```

is the event which is thrown after you finished your work.