# C# Long process with timeout and LoadingForm

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a windows form aplication.

I want to run a longprocess( coupe of seconds), while it runs i want to show a LoadingForm, and I also want to set a timeout.

I tried setting a timer to my process from a new thread, but LoadingForm doesnt alow that.

I need Something like:

```
LoadingForm m_LoadingFrom = new LoadingForm("Checking..");

private void ShowLoadingForm()
{
    m_LoadingFrom.Show();
}

private void CloseLoadingForm()
{
    m_LoadingFrom.Close();
}

private LongProcess()
{
    try{
         ShowLoadingForm();
         //doWork()..
         CloseLoadingForm(); 
    }catch(Exception e){ // timeout
         CloseLoadingForm();   
    }         
}
```

Comment: This has been asked many times. Use Control.Invoke to schedule the Open and Close operations to the main thread.

Comment: This never gives the "loading form" a chance to paint itself.  So you just don't see it.  Use a BackgroundWorker for the "long process" so you don't hang the UI thread.  If that scares you then add `m_LoadingFrom.Update();` after the Show() call.

Comment: You may want to look into my answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750498/change-label-text-while-winform-is-open/16750573#16750573 it's the same principle

Answer (score 0):

You can use [async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) and await keywords to implement this easily.